# g++ does not compile my source. Maybe some template error?

Tags: c++

I 've this template class:

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/insert.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/list.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

template<typename IntType>
class IntervalSet {
private:
    boost::icl::interval_set<IntType> impl;
    bool readonly;

    bool doIchangeReadOnly() {
        if(readonly){
            // ERROR MESSAGE
        }

        return false;
    }
public:
    IntervalSet(const boost::icl::interval_set<IntType> &c) : impl(c), readonly(false) {}
    IntervalSet(){}

    static const IntervalSet EMPTY_SET;

    static IntervalSet of(IntType a) {
        IntervalSet r;
        r.add(a);
        return r;
    }

    // Create a set with all ints within range [a..b] (inclusive)
    static IntervalSet of(IntType a, IntType b) {
        IntervalSet r;
        r.add(a, b);
        return r;
    }

    // Add element el to the set.
    void add(IntType el) {
        if(doIchangeReadOnly()) return;

        impl += el;
    }

    // Add interval; i.e., add all integers from a to b to set.
    //  If b<a, do nothing.
    //  Keep list in sorted order (by left range value).
    //  If overlap, combine ranges.  For example,
    //  If this is {1..5, 10..20}, adding 6..7 yields
    //  {1..5, 6..7, 10..20}.  Adding 4..8 yields {1..8, 10..20}.
    void add(IntType a, IntType b) {
        if(doIchangeReadOnly() || b<a) return;

        impl.add(boost::icl::interval<int>::type(a, b));
    }

    const boost::icl::interval_set<IntType>& data() const{
        return impl;
    }

    void clear() {
        if(doIchangeReadOnly()) return;

        impl.clear();
    }

    // Remove element el from the set.
    void remove(IntType el) {
        if(doIchangeReadOnly()) return;

        impl -= el;
    }

    // Add all elements from incoming set to this set.
    // Return "this" so we can chain calls.
    IntervalSet<IntType>& addAll(const IntervalSet<IntType> &set) {
        if(doIchangeReadOnly()) return *this;

        impl += set.impl;
        return *this;
    }

    // Return the intersection of this set with the argument, creating a new set.
    IntervalSet<IntType> and(IntervalSet<IntType> a) const {
        a.impl &= impl;
        return a;
    }
};

template<typename IntType>
const IntervalSet<IntType> IntervalSet<IntType>::EMPTY_SET = IntervalSet<IntType<();
```

g++ only compiles my sources, when I remove the last method definition (`IntervalSet<IntType>` and `(IntervalSet<IntType> a) const`).

My Question:
What the heck am I doing wrong?

Error messages from g++:

```
 \m.cpp     137     error: expected ')' before 'a'
 \m.cpp     137     error: 'a' does not name a type
```

Answer (score 1):

At least one error is:

```
IntervalSet<IntType<();
                   ^^?
```

should be:

```
 IntervalSet<IntType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are defining a template function in a cpp file.

Template functions must be defined and implemented in header files. There are several questions concerning this on Stack Overflow, e.g. [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: But IntervalSet<IntType> and(IntervalSet<IntType> a) const; is not a template function, because inside the template class should IntType be treated like a regular type.

Comment: Your explanation does not make sense to me. The type of impl is based on the template, how can the compiler know how to treat it without considering all possible types ?

Comment: For example I instanciate t1 and t2 with 'IntervalSet<int> t1=IntervalSet<int>::of(1, 10), t2=IntervalSet<int>::of(30, 40);'. When I call 'IntervalSet<int> t3 = t1.add(t2);', t1.add(t2) will return a IntervalSet<int> (there is no need to consider all possible types, because add is no template method)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the error:

The code does not compile, because and is considered a keyword by gcc:

Change

```
IntervalSet<IntType> and(IntervalSet<IntType> a) const {
```

to

```
IntervalSet<IntType> AND(IntervalSet<IntType> a) const
```

and it works fine.